# pyqt5 sizing correctly a tableview element in a tabbed widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlayout

I'm not able to size correctly a table view element (self.table_View_1) inside a tab,

I tried different approaches like containers, layout and so on without reaching the objective.

The code refer to a model class that allows to show pandas data frame inside the table view.

here's the code:

```
import sys

import Mod_PX
from PandasModel import PandasModel

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QTabWidget, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QMainWindow, QGroupBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot


class ProgramWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setup_main_window()
        self.set_window_layout()

    def setup_main_window(self):
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.resize( 800, 350  )
        self.setWindowTitle( "ProjectX" )

    def set_window_layout(self):

        self.vbox_1 = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.hgroup_2 = QGroupBox()
        self.hlayout_2 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hgroup_2.setLayout(self.hlayout_2)
        self.btn_Analisi = QPushButton('Analisi', self)
        self.btn_Help = QPushButton('Help')
        self.btn_Wiz = QPushButton('Wizard')
        self.btn_Analisi.clicked.connect(self.loadFile)
        self.hlayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_Analisi)
        self.hlayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_Help)
        self.hlayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_Wiz)
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.hgroup_2)

        # Initialize tabs_1 screen
        self.tabs_1 = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1_1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2_1 = QWidget()
        self.tab3_1 = QWidget()
        # Add tabs
        self.tabs_1.addTab(self.tab1_1, "WWA")
        self.tabs_1.addTab(self.tab2_1, "WTP")
        self.tabs_1.addTab(self.tab3_1, "WTW")
        # Add tabs to widget
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.tabs_1)

        # Initialize tabs_2 screen
        self.tabs_2 = QTabWidget(self.tab1_1)
        self.tab1_2 = QWidget()
        self.tab2_2 = QWidget()
        self.tabs_2.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)
        self.vbox_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.tab1_1)
        # Add tabs
        self.tabs_2.addTab(self.tab1_2, "Foglio 1")
        self.tabs_2.addTab(self.tab2_2, "Foglio 2")
        #Add tabs to widget
        self.table_View_1 = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab1_2)
        self.table_View_1.setObjectName("table_View_1")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.table_View_1.setFont(font)
        self.table_View_1.setGeometry(0,0,self.tab1_2.width(),self.tab1_2.height())
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.tabs_2)

        self.show()


    @pyqtSlot()
    def loadFile(self):
        df = Mod_PX.sheet_b()
        model = PandasModel(df)
        self.table_View_1.setModel(model)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    programWindow = ProgramWindow()

    programWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here the GUI with the table not correctly sized:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must correctly state the layouts and you should not use setGeometry since that is the task of the layouts. I have modified the structure of your code to have an order so at the end I point out the relationship between the layouts.

```
def set_window_layout(self):
    #buttons
    self.btn_Analisi = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Analisi')
    self.btn_Help = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Help')
    self.btn_Wiz = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Wizard')

    # Initialize tabs_1 screen
    self.tabs_1 = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
    self.tab1_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.tab2_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.tab3_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    # Add tabs
    self.tabs_1.addTab(self.tab1_1, "WWA")
    self.tabs_1.addTab(self.tab2_1, "WTP")
    self.tabs_1.addTab(self.tab3_1, "WTW")

    # Initialize tabs_2 screen
    self.tabs_2 = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
    self.tab1_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.tab2_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.tabs_2.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)
    # Add tabs
    self.tabs_2.addTab(self.tab1_2, "Foglio 1")
    self.tabs_2.addTab(self.tab2_2, "Foglio 2")

    self.table_View_1 = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    self.table_View_1.setFont(font)

    # connections
    self.btn_Analisi.clicked.connect(self.loadFile)

    # layouts
    vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
    hgroup = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
    vbox.addWidget(hgroup)
    hlay_group = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(hgroup)
    hlay_group.addWidget(self.btn_Analisi)
    hlay_group.addWidget(self.btn_Help)
    hlay_group.addWidget(self.btn_Wiz)
    vbox.addWidget(self.tabs_1)

    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tab1_1)
    lay.addWidget(self.tabs_2)

    lay_tableview = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tab1_2)
    lay_tableview.addWidget(self.table_View_1)
```

Comment: Great. I've to understand better layout usage in order to avoid confusion. I'm looking for good tutorial/courses online for that but there are not a lot. Tks.